# Apache ssh server public key authentication

Tags: authentication, ssh, key, public, mina

I want to use the Apache ssh server, which is available at https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project.
How can I set (configure) the client's public key on the ssh server in order to public key authentication?

Comment: I found this [documentation for SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/apidocs/org/apache/sshd/server/keyprovider/SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider.html), but it's not much help. Maybe you need to view the source code for Apache SSHD.